# Comparing execution context stacks in javascript

Tags: javascript, executioncontext

I am using the strict mode. I want to compare if two calls to the same function were made in the same execution context stack.

Eg 1: If two independent event handlers A and B fired and each of them called C, then I want to know that the call to C was made in different execution context stacks.

```
A->C
B->C
```

Eg 2: If function A called C which Called B which again called C, then I want to ascertain that the two calls to C were made in the same execution context stack.

```
A->C->B->C
```

I need this behaviour because I am implementation application transactions in Javascript and I would like to be able to support nested transactions. As we are writing strict code, I am looking for solutions that dont use arguments, callee, caller objects.

Also keep in mind that A, B, C all of them can be asynchronous and C will not immediately run to completion upon invokation. And this why why using counters as described below will not work in async scenarios

```
C() {
   return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
        let result = someFunction();
        return result;
   })
}

B() {
    doSomethingSync();

    if(someCondition) {
        C();
    }
}
```

C is async. Using counters, it means that two independent event handlers call C, both of them increment the counter before either gets a chance to decrement it

Comment: But if A calls B which calls C, then the execution context stack will be different.

Comment: Yes. But how do I identify this difference without accessing arguments.callee because that is prohibited by ES5 strict mode

Comment: But this makes no sense. Each time C is called, a new ECMAScript code execution context is pushed to the execution context stack. So two different calls to C will have different execution context stacks.

Comment: Based on your comments on my answer, it seems likely to me that the question is unclear about what it's trying to detect, or that you (with respect!) have some fundamental misunderstandings about JavaScript's run-to-completion semantics. Please update the question with a runnable [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` button) demonstrating the situation you're trying to detect, and the situation you're not trying to detect, so we're working with tangibles, not abstracts.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you're running this in a single-threaded context (such as a browser<sup>1</sup> or NodeJS).

If so, the difference between the two scenarios is that C is called via indirect recursion, so a simple state variable can tell you whether that's happened.

The simplest form is of course a counter:

```
var callstoC = 0;
function C() {
    ++callsToC;
    // ...code here that checks `callsToC`: If it's `1`, it's not recursive;
    // if it's `> 1`, it's recursive (indirectly or directly)
    --callsToC;
}
```

You can make it more complex than that for keeping track of state (such as using an array to remember what the arguments are to each call in case that's important — for instance, for reporting purposes).

Obviously it's key that all routes out of the function correctly record that you've left the function.

Live example:

```js
function hook(selector, event, handler) {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  for (var n = 0; n < elements.length; ++n) {
    elements[n].addEventListener(
      event,
      handler,
      false
    );
  }
}
hook("#btnA, #btnB, #btnD", "click", function() {
  console.log(this.id + " calling C");
  C(this.id == "btnD");
});

var callsToC = 0;
function C(flag) {
  ++callsToC;
  console.log("C called with flag = " + flag + ", callsToC = " + callsToC);
  if (flag) {
    D();
  }
  console.log("C about to decrement and exit, callsToC = " + callsToC);
  --callsToC;
}
function D() {
  console.log("D calling C");
  C(false);
  console.log("D done");
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 80% !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btnA" value="A">
<input type="button" id="btnB" value="B">
<input type="button" id="btnD" value="D">
```

---

In a comment you had a concern that `callsToC` was global. It doesn't have to be, and I wouldn't make it global or even as visible as `C`; I just didn't want to complicate the example. I'd make it truly private to C like this:

```
var C = (function() {
    var callsToC = 0;
    return function C() {
        // ...
    };
})();
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Although browsers support multiple threads (via web workers), they don't support the *same function* being used in multiple threads; each thread gets its own global context.

Comment: As callstoC is stored in global context, it would be updated in same fashion if its called from two different event handlers or if it is called twice in the same execution stack. Not sure how it helps to determine if the 2nd caller is in the same execution stack

Comment: @prk68: It's not necessarily global (in fact, I would certainly make it non-global, but didn't complicate the above with that). As to your question: We know it's the same stack because it has to be, there's no other way (other than coding bugs) for `callsToC` to be `> 1` than a recursive call to `C` (directly or indirectly) given a single-threaded context.

Comment: May be I tried to oversimplify the problem in the question. There could be 10 different event handlers. So if the calltoC was 3, it could still be the case that it is a direct call.

Comment: @prk68: No, it couldn't. Not unless `C` calls itself, or calls a function that calls `C`, or calls a function that calls a function that calls `C` (etc.); e.g., recursion. It doesn't matter how many event handlers might call C; each time they do, `callsToC` will be `1` barring recursion.

Comment: Event handlers arent synchornous. So you could have event handler A increment callsToC, then break,  event handler B increment callsToC and break and so on. So when a new event handlers calls C, it sees the value callsToC to be 2 because the first two event handlers havent finished execution yet and so havent decremented callsToC

Comment: @prk68: Event handlers being asynchronous is irrelevant. The *call* to an event handler is run to completion; this is a requirement of JavaScript's semantics. I have no idea what your "break" is meant to be there, but once `C` is called, that call **will** complete and `callsToC` will be decremented again, not stay incremented as you've described.

Comment: But if event handlers start network bound operations and/or wait on promises, the single JS thread will not wait for it to run to competition. JS engine will put the event handler execution on hold and move onto the next item in the event queue

Comment: @prk68: That's the missing part of your question, then. You never said you needed to handle the situation where C started an *asynchronous* process (after which C returns, of course) and you wanted to know if C was called again before *that process* completed. Again, please update the question in line with my comment on the question so we can help you.

Comment: Done. Does it help ?

Comment: @prk68: Not really. Please re-read [the comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41957131/comparing-execution-context-stacks-in-javascript/41957207?noredirect=1#comment71097764_41957131). What you've done isn't runnable, doesn't demonstrate the scenario you want to catch, and doesn't demonstrate the scenario you don't want to catch.